# python Django command argument parsing returning an array

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have this simple Django command I'm writing as such:

```
def add_arguments(self, parser):
    parser.add_argument('--type', nargs='+', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--overwrite', nargs='?', type=bool, default=False)
    parser.add_argument('--unsubscribe', nargs='?',
                        type=bool, default=False)

def handle(self, *args, **options):

    print(options['type'])
```

If I run `myCommand --type=all` I see my type printed as `['all']`. Why is this coming back as an array? I just want the string value `all`.

Answer (score 4):

Its because your nargs, where you tell it to give you a list.

Read more here https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs

where we can see that

> '+'. Just like '*', all command-line args present are gathered into a list. Additionally, an error message will be generated if there wasn’t at least one command-line argument present.

So you probably want '?' which parses a single value.